# Prevent Dropdown from Semantic UI to change its shown value

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using [this Dropdown](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#selection) from Semantic UI and I would like to keep it the top unchanged, even when an option is selected.

In their example, it is Gender and when one selects Male of Female, the Gender is replaced by that value.

Is it a way to avoid that change so the dropdown shows Gender even if one of its options are selected?

This is the code:

```
import Dropdown from '../Dropdown.component';

<Dropdown // this is the Dropdown created based on the one from Semantic UI
  className="hello-dropdown"
  placeholder="Company"
  onChange={this.doSomething}
  options={someOptions}
/>;
```

**Dropdown.component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import './Dropdown.styles.scss';

export default ({ placeholder, options, onChange, name, className }) => (
  <Dropdown
    className={className}
    name={name}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    search
    selection
    options={options}
    onChange={onChange}
    clearable
  />
);
```

I guess it is something related to `placeholder={placeholder}` but not sure

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `value` prop on the `Dropdown` component to an empty string. This way it will always show the placeholder text:

```
// ...
<Dropdown
  className={className}
  name={name}
  placeholder={placeholder}
  value=""
  search
  selection
  options={options}
  onChange={onChange}
  clearable
/>
// ...
```